# Graph API does not return all events for query

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the following query:

https://graph.facebook.com/search?access_token=my_token&q=10k&type=event&fields=name,place,owner&limit=100

to retrieve all events that match the keyword '10k' (looking for running events of distance 10k, usually the distance is part of the event name).

In the results I get back, I don't see the same events as when searching facebook.com for '10k' and then looking at the 'Events' tab.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Many thanks for your help

Comment: The search on facebook.com, and the API search are two different things - and the latter is pretty limited.

Comment: Thanks, @CBroe. So fundamentally I cannot expect to get the same results through the API? Are the limitations/differences documented so I figure out what's possible with the API?

Comment: What you can search for via API is listed here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#search Results will be tailored to the requesting user.

Comment: Thanks again, @CBroe. I am familiar with the available fields for the API. What I don't understand is why I'm not seeing some results I would expect to be included in the my API query. I'm the same user searching through browser and graph API. The events I'm querying are public, as far as I can tell. What determines (in my user profile, event privacy settings or otherwise) what is returned by the API?

Comment: Dunno, that is not officially documented anywhere as far as I know. API search is pretty rudimentary; don’t expect that it will find “everything” there is on FB. At best, you will get a small extract ...

Comment: Thanks again for your help, @CBroe - I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the recent Facebook API changes being made.

> We anticipate that some of the changes we announced today might inconvenience the way some businesses or services operate. That’s why we’ve also created a new escalation process. If your business or service was impacted by these changes and you have an urgent issue in need of resolution, please fill out [this form](https://go.fb.com/2018-FB4D-platform-review-form.html) and someone from our team will get in touch with you.

You can read more about this update here: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/04/04/facebook-api-platform-product-changes/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, events API been returning nil events for a few days now. Queries that worked before don't return anything. I think it'll be back after they sort out their privacy issues. Knee jerk reaction. I was only asking public events, no special permission fields.